# How to explode multiple string with quotes

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to explode multiple string like this:

```
$str1 = 'Apple\'s OS and the "Microsoft OS", ----- any text with quotes & symbols ---- ';
$str2 = 'Sony\'s Laptop and the "Toshiba\'s"';

$string = "".$str1.",".$str2."";
$result = explode(',',$string);

echo "Str1 : ".$result[0]."<br/>";
echo "Str2 : ".$result[1]."<br/>";
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
Str1 : Apple's OS and the "Microsoft OS"
Str2 : ----- any text with quotes & symbols ---- //This Str2 actually is the part of Str1
```

I want this output  -->

```
`Str1 : Apple's OS and the "Microsoft OS, ----- any text with quotes & symbols ---- 
Str2 : Sony's Laptop and the "Toshiba's"`
```

Please help.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what it should. You should show what you expect. Maybe you shouldn't be using the explode function.

Comment: If you're looking for $str2. Try `end($result)`. Or iterate through the entire array.

Comment: Yes, you should be aware that in this case there is a `$result[3]`

Comment: What is expected? Works as I'd expect, https://3v4l.org/iEsDH.

Comment: Sounds like you want to explode $str1 and $str2 separately.

Comment: Hello Brian, Actually I'm trying this cuz I've multiple string data with lots of quotes in it in my db in array format like this --> "a","b","c"  but a contains large text with quotes, b also the same so i have to explode it individually without skipping any text in the line like in my output str1 missing some of its part. which is now the part of str2 and str2 actually has been lost..

Comment: Hi  jh1711, No its not what I'm looking for. :(

Comment: You should revise your question to show exactly the expected output.

Comment: Hi Jarzon, I think you've got my point.. I want $str1 to be displayed in result[0],  but it skipping some text. and counts the skipped text as result[1].

Comment: How is that: [3v4l.org/6tSiS](https://3v4l.org/6tSiS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that does that

```
function implodeStrings(...$array) {
    $output = [];

    foreach($array as $str) {
        $output[] = $str;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

[You can find a working example here.](https://3v4l.org/i2Dkh)